# Is b^n = Θ(c^n) for all b,c > 1?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I have been trying to find a solution where 0 < k_1*c^n <= b^n <= k_2*c^n, but so far I've had no luck. From my understanding of the Wikipedia article on [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities) all functions on the form a^n should have the same asymptotic growth. Is this false?

Answer (score 3):

False. Suppose, for simplicity, `b = 2*a`. `b^n` is `2^n*a^n`. For any constant `c`, there exists `n` such that `2^n > c`, so `b^n > c * a^n`.

It is impossible to find constants m and c such that, for all `n>m, b^n <= c*a^n`, so `b^n` is not `O(a^n)`.

Comment: So more generally, O(b^n) is a strict superset of O(a^n) for any 1 < a < b.